# 2D fitting lines in 3D plot

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I wish to put 2D curve fitting to different axis within a 3D plot. I am attaching an image for reference.

[image: representational image]
on this actual data set:
[image: Actual Data set]

As you can see the curve fitting for x and y axis is at z=0 value, I need that at say z=10.

Further, when I try to do curve fitting for x and z data set or y and z data set, the fitted curve instead of appearing on the the X-Z plane or Y-Z plane, is appearing on the X-Y plane.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: I solved the problem using polyfit. Here is the solution.  


`% Curve Fitting for HS6-5-3 PM
[xData9, yData9, zData9] = prepareCurveData( Cycles_HS6_PM, SqRt_Area_HS6_PM, Tension_HS6_PM );

%Fit model to data.
y=0+zeros(42,1);
z = Tension_HS6_PM
p = polyfit(zData9, xData9,1);
x = polyval(p,z);
h=plot3(x,y,z)
h.Color = '#9475EB'; % Indigo`

Comment: PS: I tried to use new line to help understand the code better, but the SO comments are limited in new line capabilities it seems.